# WSO2 Databases Function

Tags: database, wso2, api-manager

I have a question around databases that are used for WSO2 API manager. I understand that WSO2 API manager comes with embedded H2 database, but if we want to use an external database such as PostgreSQL or any other industry standard DB.

Which of the WSO2 datasources should we move to external database and for which one we should keep on using H2 or we should move all of them to external database?

Which one are dynamic databases and which one are static databases meaning which one changes the most and which one don't change much?

***For eg.*** What is the function of all these databases and where they should be for production purposes?

**WSO2_CARBON_DB**

**WSO2AM_DB**

**WSO2UM_DB**

**WSO2REG_DB**

**WSO2AM_STATS_DB**

**WSO2_MB_STORE_DB**

**GEO_LOCATION_DATA**

for Analytics

**WSO2_ANALYTICS_EVENT_STORE_DB**

**WSO2_ANALYTICS_PROCESSED_DATA_STORE_DB**

Answer (score 0):

All the databases are recommended to share with external databases except for WSO2_CARBON_DB. All the data sources are dynamic.

You can find more details about data sources in the [wso2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0).

Comment: If I am thinking right as WSO2_CARBON_DB contains user and registry DB  but once we have separate DBs for user and registry, we can remove (comment out) WSO2_CARBON_DB or keep this on H2 database? Also what data does WSO2_CARBON_DB holds other than user and registry data?

Comment: Yes. It holds instance specific data and local cache.